# Why blank space occurs in table on TCPDF

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server, tcpdf

How to avoid the blank space below tcpdf table row on php and mssql. please check the screenshot attached.

[Please check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv0fQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Would you please add above `CSS` to your `td` should work?

Comment: <style>
.qd{
padding-bottom:4px; 
padding-top:4px; 
font-size:13px; 
text-align:left;
width:190px;
border: 1px solid black; 
border-left: 0px; }
.body{
height: 842px;
width: 595px;
/* to centre page on screen*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

'<table class="body">
<tr>
 <td class="qd">&nbsp;'.$quotation['sc_a_b'].'</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="qd">&nbsp;'.$quotation['sc_a_c'].'</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<table>'